# Yii2 migrate Setting unknown property: yii\caching\FileCache::backuprestore

Tags: php, yii2, migration, database-migration, yii2-advanced-app

I know how the migrate works, and have created migrations files before,
so I created my migrate file like this:

```
php yii migrate/create implants_type
```

it gives me:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

class m180403_081742_implants_type extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {

    }

    public function down()
    {
        echo "m180403_081742_implants_type cannot be reverted.\n";

        return false;
    } 

    /*
    // Use safeUp/safeDown to run migration code within a transaction
    public function safeUp()
    {
    }

    public function safeDown()
    {
    }
    */
}
```

then

```
php yii migrate/create create_implants_type_table
```

and I updated the file that generated like this:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

class m180403_081750_create_implants_type_table extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('implants_type_table', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'implants_name'=>$this->string(),

        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('implants_type_table');
    }
}
```

then I used

```
./yii migrate
```

but an error occurred:

> Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\caching\FileCache::backuprestore'

I updated my composer now, and the problem still exists.

Comment: why arent you using php yii migrate ?

Comment: there isnt anything wrong with the migrations you have written. check the cache config

Comment: @mrateb Read about https://git-scm.com/ plz !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have improperly configured `cache` component. Double-check your console configuration: search `backuprestore` in your project end remove this setting from configuration - there is no such property in official cache components, so you probably messed up something.

This is probably unrelated to migrations - `db` component just tries to use `cache` component to cache DB schema, which triggers this error.

Comment: that's right  there was in Main.php in common folder `  'backuprestore' => [ 'class' => '\oe\modules\backuprestore\Module'], `